# Dynamically adding imageViews onto a linear Layout

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android. I have a requirement where I have to add the imageViews dynamically onto a linear layout and then have to animate each image individually.

I am not aware of the way to add the imageViews dynamically onto a linear layout. Plz help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can add `view` dynamically like this.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams imParams = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ImageView imSex = new ImageView(context);
imSex.setImageResource(getmyImage());

mainlayout.addView(imSex,imParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

see this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.rainbow);
    ImageView tv1 = new ImageView (this);
    tv1.setImageresorce(R.drawable.image1);
    ImageView tv2 = new ImageView (this);
    tv2.setImageresorce(R.drawable.image2);
    ImageView tv3 = new ImageView (this);

    tv3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv3.setImageresorce(R.drawable.image3);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    ll.addView(tv1);
    ll.addView(tv2);
    ll.addView(tv3);
    setContentView(ll);
}
```

see this usefull data

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/

Answer (score 1):

You can give this piece of code a try. It also has the bit for setting the dimensions for the `ImageView` along with a margin between multiple `ImageView's`. The `int dimens = 45` and the `int dimensMargin = 4;` are `pixel` values and are being converted into dp.

The `LinearLayout linlaLikes` has to be in your layout `XML` and then cast in your activity.

```
LinearLayout linlaLikes = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlaLikes);
ImageView imgUsers = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

// SET THE IMAGEVIEW DIMENSIONS
int dimens = 45;
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int finalDimens = (int)(dimens * density);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgvwDimens = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(finalDimens, finalDimens);
imgUsers.setLayoutParams(imgvwDimens);

// SET SCALETYPE
imgUsers.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

// SET THE MARGIN
int dimensMargin = 4;
float densityMargin = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int finalDimensMargin = (int)(dimensMargin * densityMargin);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgvwMargin = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(finalDimens, finalDimens);
imgvwMargin.setMargins(finalDimensMargin, finalDimensMargin, finalDimensMargin, finalDimensMargin);

// SET YOUR IMAGER SOURCE TO YOUR NEW IMAGEVIEW HERE

// ADD THE NEW IMAGEVIEW WITH THE PROFILE PICTURE LOADED TO THE LINEARLAYOUT
linlaLikes.addView(imgUsers, imgvwMargin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use fragment for this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExampleFragment imageFragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.image_container, imageFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I managed to fulfill the requiremnets in gridView only. But now am stuck with an issue. The problem is the requirement states that when the View of the GridView is filled and when the view moves down then the vertical scroll should scroll down automatically to show up the newly loaded images. I tried using gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
gridView.setSelection(position);  But on using them my app is crashing. How to enable auto vertical scroll for a GridView? Help me out..

Comment: post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        gridView.setSelection(index);
    }
});